# Caveats of running software inside the Users directory

Tags: windows

I have some applications that I'd like to stay with my user forever. I've invested a lot of time in customizing them, and doing it from the start would be rather annoying. To that end, I'm thinking about moving them inside my Users folder, as it is the most redundantly-backed up directory on my computer.

Are there any concerns associated with running software inside the Users directory, save for updating absolute paths? File permissions and security come to mind.

Comment: Google Chrome does this; it runs from the user's `%APPDATA%` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really thin that you have anything to worry about really with regard to permissions, but if you want, you can set up the permissions of any folder to like those of say, program files.

To do that, (this assumes that you are using windows 7),

- Right click on the folder, and select properties.
- On the security tab, click advanced
- Click change permissions
- Uncheck the include inheritable permissions
- Remove your user from the list of users in the box, and add Users to the list.
- Hit apply (three times, one for each box)

This will then prompt for administrative permission every time someone tries to change that folder, or its contents in any way.